# Which of the platform provides fast & reliable internet connectivity for API?

Tags: api, web-scraping, cheerio

My API requires reliable and fast internet connectivity (for scraping).

I tested it on my internet connection, the time it took to fetch & process information rounds up to 20 seconds on slow connectivity, 2 seconds on fast connectivity.

Is there any platform or service (preferably free) that best provides reliable and fast internet connectivity, if I wish to deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be honest: The more you pay the more you get.
But it doesn't help when the client (mobile) has slow connectivity.
My opinion: use Azure to host your app and use the nearest region(s).

Comment: how about heroku or aws?

Comment: ok.: any cloud that supports many regions and has a strong network backbone.